# Windows redistribution licensing for virtual demos

Tags: windows, licensing

What are the license restrictions surrounding the redistribution of Windows OSes as part of virtual demos?

I am looking to make available demo versions of my software as already installed and configured on a VHD (or whatever the VMWare equivalent is). I was told that this is not possible because MS does not allow the Windows OS to be redistributed that way (even trial/demo versions). Can anyone point me to a definitive source (MS license terms maybe?) that specifies what the requirements are? Or at least an official "this is not possible"?

MS seems to be distributing their virtual training labs and product demos more and more as a VHD download. I was hoping to be able to do the same.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it's very likely that you can distribute Windows as part of your demo, but you're going to have to buy a license for every copy. I'm assuming you wanted to avoid that.

Your sources are correct; this isn't possible. Microsoft distributes windows on VHD's for training and demonstration purposes because it can. I'm not aware of any organization being given permission to distribute Windows as you describe. You are not likely to find an official "this is not possible", simply because licenses define what you *can* do, not (in general) what you *can't*. Most of the prohibitions in a license agreement are stipulations that are part of the *granting* of some other right. You won't find a comprehensive list of what's disallowed, simply because that's obviously impossible.

The only way to get an official response is to ask your Microsoft representative, assuming that you have one (if your organization has an EA, for example, the EA representative would be the person to talk to).

Comment: I was trying to avoid paying for it (doesn't MS have enough problems not allowing others to do things they make easy/free for themselves ;). According to MS - you have to run down the developer partner (or reseller) trail for this to even be a possibility. Prices/options are only available at that point and evaluated on a case by case basis. I was kinda looking for a better answer than "call MS" since I was trying to avoid going through their call tree of hell - but since you are the only answer given...